# find set within timestamp range

Tags: php, arrays, time

I have an array with numerous timestamps.
I need to find all the timestamps from the last 30 min

current code:

```
            //$history is a JSON decoded stream of arrays, of variable lengths
            $hist = array();
            foreach($history as $newday){
                    if($newday['Closed'] == $val){
                            array_push($hist, $newday['Closed']);
                    }
            }
            var_dump($hist);
```

sample array data:

```
array(24) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "2016-08-18T05:24:40.47"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "2016-08-14T11:43:25.917"
  [2]=>
  string(23) "2016-08-16T08:26:39.693"
  [3]=>
  string(23) "2016-08-18T04:51:45.553"
```

How do I calculate/find the last 30 of timestamps ($hist) in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateTime` class is great for this kind of thing.

```
$timestamps = [
    "2016-08-18T05:24:40.47",
    "2016-08-14T11:43:25.917",
    "2016-08-16T08:26:39.693",
    "2016-08-18T04:51:45.553",
    "2016-08-18T16:30:45.553",
];

$timeLimit = new DateTime('now');
$timeLimit->sub(new DateInterval('PT30M'));

$recentTimestamps = [];
foreach ($timestamps as $timestamp) {
    $timestampDate = new DateTime($timestamp);
    if ($timestampDate > $timeLimit) {
        $recentTimestamps[] = $timestamp;
    }
}

var_dump($recentTimestamps);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(23) "2016-08-18T16:30:45.553"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give you an hint here:

`strtotime("2016-08-18T05:24:40.47") >= strtotime('-30minutes')`

have a try.